# I have SVG element displaying on some pages but not others, same browser, platform et al

Tags: image, svg, vector-graphics

The folowing code has a bunch of svg triangles

```
<svg class="constellation" viewBox="0 0 275 275">
<use class="constellation__1" xlink:href="#constellation-svg" data-props="190x190,83,38" transform="scale(0.693582)" x="119.66851188213664" y="54.78800219180441"></use>
<use class="constellation__2" xlink:href="#constellation-svg" data-props="107x107,64,67" transform="scale(0.390596)" x="163.851982" y="171.532544"></use>
<use class="constellation__3" xlink:href="#constellation-svg" data-props="53x53,148,200" transform="scale(0.193473)" x="764.96462" y="1033.735676"></use>
```

This svg code appears on two different pages.  On one page it display on the other it does not.  I did not set up either page but have been tasked with getting the svg to show up on both.

Can anyone tell me why they do not appear in the second link?  I have compared the css and the html and cannot find the difference.

Comment: You have not put your problem code in the question, you've only provided links to it. That's not really allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found that the svg "use" element requires a source svg.  It does not contain actual svg vector coordinates so using the svg "use" elements requires a pointer to the actual svg element in the DOM.  For instance the "use" element requires an attribute such as this: xlink:href="#some_id_of_an_actual_svg" which points at the svg element that contains the actual vector info.  svg id="some_id_of_an_actual_svg"

So 
`<svg class="my-svg">` 
`<use xlink:href="#some_id_of_an_actual_svg"></use>`
`</svg>`

When used alone is not a svg, it is a pointer to a svg which must be in the DOM containing the id referenced in the xlink:href attribute.

`<svg id="some_id_of_an_actual_svg" viewBox="0 0 467 467" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-width="0" d="M466.2 455.5V31.2C466.2 14.5 452.7 1 436 1H11.7C5.8 1 1 5.8 1 11.7c0 3 1.2 5.6 3.1 7.6l443.8 443.8c1.9 1.9 4.6 3.1 7.6 3.1 5.9 0 10.7-4.8 10.7-10.7" class="some-class"></path></svg>`

Adding a svg "use"  alone will not display anything, both svg elements must exist.  The process is to hide the source svg and use the "use" element to create multiple versions of it and style them differently.  Or even to use the source svg, unhidden to represent your first instance and then use the "use" elements to create more instances of them to deal with differently.